# React Private Route Redirect Condition Is Ignored

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, local-storage, react-router-dom

Every time I try to navigate to a page after the token expires, I am not redirected to my landing page. Ideally, I would like to be redirected to my landing page after my token expires. My status variable does update when the token expires but gets ignored when rendering the Redirect component. I think my Private Route may be written wrong.

**App.js**

````
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import LandingPage from './pages/LandingPage';
import ViewAllRecipe from './pages/ViewAllRecipe';
import AddRecipe from './pages/AddRecipe';
import EditRecipe from './pages/EditRecipe';
import SingleRecipe from './pages/SingleRecipe';
import axios from 'axios';

var status;

async function validToken(){
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    try{
    const res = await axios.post('/api/auth/verify',
        {token: token},
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}},        
        );
     if(res.data.status===200){
       status = 200;
    }
    else{
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      status= 401;
    }   
      }
    catch(err){
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      status=500;
    }
}


function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  validToken();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() =>
      status!==200 ? (
          <Redirect
            to="/landing"
            
          />
        ):(
          children
        )
      }
    />
  );
}



function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/landing" component={LandingPage}></Route>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/addRecipe" component={AddRecipe}></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/viewRecipes" component={ViewAllRecipe}></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/recipe/edit/:editRecipe"  component={(props) => <EditRecipe {...props}/>}></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/recipe/view/:id"  component={(props) => <SingleRecipe {...props}/>}></PrivateRoute>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App; ```
````

Comment: `validToken` is async, which means the status is changed *after* `PrivateRoute` returns the components.

Comment: @ChrisG That makes sense. How should I set it up to avoid making an async call?

Comment: It takes a moment for the auth request to finish, so how to deal with this depends on what you want to show to the user in the meantime. I'm not sure what the best approach is, tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingPage from './pages/LandingPage';
import ViewAllRecipe from './pages/ViewAllRecipe';
import AddRecipe from './pages/AddRecipe';
import EditRecipe from './pages/EditRecipe';
import SingleRecipe from './pages/SingleRecipe';
import axios from 'axios';

async function getStatus() {
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      '/api/auth/verify',
      { token: token },
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } },
    );
    if (res.data.status === 200) {
      return 200;
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      return 401;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    return 500;
  }
}

function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => setStatus(await getStatus()))();
  }, []);

  return (
    status && (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={() => (status !== 200 ? <Redirect to="/landing" /> : children)}
      />
    )
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/landing" component={LandingPage}></Route>
        <PrivateRoute
          exact
          path="/addRecipe"
          component={AddRecipe}></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute
          exact
          path="/viewRecipes"
          component={ViewAllRecipe}></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute
          exact
          path="/recipe/edit/:editRecipe"
          component={props => <EditRecipe {...props} />}></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute
          exact
          path="/recipe/view/:id"
          component={props => <SingleRecipe {...props} />}></PrivateRoute>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The useEffect with [] as the second parameter gets called only on the first render and it runs a function that checks the status and sets the state with that status. If the status is null you don't render anything because the async function hasn't run yet so you don't know the status (you could render a loading instead). When the status is the in the state it triggers a re-render with the status in the state

Comment: It still doesn't work the way I'd like. I want to check that my token is still valid every time I try to navigate. When I use the code above, it keeps saying my token is valid (200) when it should say 401or 500 since it expires within a few minutes. It doesn't call getStatus on each navigation.

Comment: Try removing the last parameter of useEffect (the []). useEffect with [] as the second parameter runs only on the first render if you want it to run on all renders you can just remove it, so no 2 parameter.

Comment: I removed it and now it renders each time. However, it still doesn't redirect to "/landing"

Comment: Can you log the status and see if it changes?

Comment: Yes. It changes from 200 to 401.

Comment: try putting key={status} on the Route component bellow {...rest}

Comment: I tried it out and it somewhat works. I can't enter the "/add" route but the last two routes "/recipe/edit/:editRecipe" and "/recipe/view/:id" are still clickable. No redirection happening in any routes.

Comment: There are 2 things you can try 1. instead of `component={props => <EditRecipe {...props} />}` try `component={EditRecipe}` or 2 you can try doing this for all the routes: `<PrivateRoute [with all the props here]> <Component /> </PrivateRoute>`